# Simple way to decompose a lists in a certain way?

Tags: list-manipulation, subset

I want to decompose one list into sublists (**each sublist is given by certain lengh** and **the sum of every sublist is given by the maximun number in `lists`**).

> For example: `lists={0,1,2,3,4}`
>
> all the sublists: `{{0, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1},{2, 2, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 0, 0}}`

The code is as following:

```
Maxnum = 4;
setlength = 3;
lists = Table[i, {i, 0, Maxnum}];
ylists = Tuples[lists, setlength];
ysublists = {};
Do[If[Total[ylists[[j]]] == Maxnum, AppendTo[ysublists, ylists[[j]]]], {j, Length@ylists}];
```

I want to know whether this is any simple way to do the same work?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use `FrobeniusSolve`:

```
allTuples[len_, sum_] := FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, len], sum]
allTuples[3, 4]

(* {{0, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 3}, {0, 2, 2}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 3}, {1,
   1, 2}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 0}, {2, 0, 2}, {2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 0}, {3, 
  0, 1}, {3, 1, 0}, {4, 0, 0}} *)
```

Comment: That's very simple and just one line code! Thank you!@C. E.

Answer (score 5):

You can get there most of the way using [`IntegerPartitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerPartitions.html), like this:

```
Maxnum = 4;
setlength = 3;
lists = Table[i, {i, 0, Maxnum}];

IntegerPartitions[Maxnum, {setlength}, lists]
(* {{4, 0, 0}, {3, 1, 0}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 1, 1}} *)
```

As you can see, this will generate all sorted solutions. If you really need all possible permutations, you can use [`Permutations`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Permutations.html) and [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html):

```
Join @@ 
 Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[Maxnum, {setlength}, lists]
(* {{4, 0, 0}, {0, 4, 0}, {0, 0, 4}, {3, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 1}, {1, 3,
   0}, {1, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 1}, {0, 1, 3}, {2, 2, 0}, {2, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 
  2}, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 1}, {1, 1, 2}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! good idea to use Permutations and IntegerPartitions together, I didn't think of the Permutations before @Lukas Lang